# Integral including trigonometric function

Tags: integration, trigonometry

$$\int \frac{1}{1+\cos(8x)}dx$$
$$\int \frac{1}{1+\sin(8x)}dx$$

How do I solve these and is substituting an option? I always seem to miscalculate when it involves sine and cosine.

Comment: Use https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/WeierstrassSubstitution.shtml

Comment: Also see [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#Third_example) from WIkipedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

Part $1$: Substitute $u = 8x$, giving us: $$I = \int \frac{1}{1+\cos 8x}\, dx = \frac18 \int \frac{1}{1+\cos u}\, du$$ Now, note that $$\frac{1}{1+\cos u} = \frac{1}{2}\sec^2 \frac{u}{2}$$

Part $2$: Substituting $u = 8x$ and giving us: $$I = \int \frac{1}{1+\sin 8x}\, dx = \frac18 \int \frac{1}{1+\sin u}\, du$$ Now, note that $$\frac{1}{1+\sin u} = \frac{\sec^2 \frac{u}{2}}{\left(\tan \frac{u}{2}+1\right)^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Another approach for Part 2 is after enforcing the substitution $u = 8x$ is to note that
$$\frac{1}{1 + \sin u} = \frac{1}{1 + \sin u} \cdot \frac{1 - \sin u}{1 - \sin u} = \frac{1 - \sin u}{\cos^2 u} = \sec^2 u - \frac{\sin u}{\cos^2 u},$$
with the final expression to the right being readily integrated.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for $\int \frac{1}{1+\cos(8x)}dx$: substitute $t:=8x$ and $dt=8dx$

then you get $\int \frac{1}{1+\cos(t)}dt$ substitute $k:=\tan(t/2)$.

notice that $\sin(t)=\frac{2k}{k^2+1}, \cos(t)=\frac{1-k^2}{k^2+1}$

therefore:
$$=\frac 1 8 \int \frac{2}{(k^2)(\frac{1-k^2}{k^2+1}+1)}dk$$

Answer (score 0):

Use first $u=8x$. Now
$$
\int\frac{1}{1+\sin u}\,du
$$
With $t=\tan(u/2)$, we have
$$
1+\sin u=1+\frac{2t}{1+t^2}=\frac{(1+t)^2}{1+t^2}
\qquad
du=\frac{2}{1+t^2}\,dt
$$
so the integral becomes
$$
\int\frac{2}{(1+t)^2}\,dt=-\frac{2}{1+t}=-\frac{2}{1+\tan(u/2)}
$$
Also, with $u=\pi/2-v$
$$
\int\frac{1}{1+\cos u}\,du=
-\int\frac{1}{1+\sin v}\,dv
=\frac{2}{1+\tan(v/2)}=
\frac{2}{1+\tan(\pi/4-u/2)}
$$